# Set the value of a variable with the result of a command in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

When working in a **Bash** environment, to set the value of a variable as the result of a command, I usually do:

```
var=$(command -args)
```

where `var` is the variable set by the command `command -args`. I can then access that variable as `$var`.

A more conventional way to do this which is compatible with almost every Unix shell is:

```
set var=`command -args`
```

That said, how can I set the value of a variable with the result of a command in a **Windows batch file**? I've tried:

```
set var=command -args
```

But I find that `var` is set to `command -args` rather than the output of the command.

Answer (score 68):

To do what [Jesse describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/889578), from a Windows batch file you will need to write:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do @set foobar=%%a
```

But, I instead suggest using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.org) on your Windows system if you are used to Unix-type scripting.

Comment: use `for /f "delims=" %a in ('ver') do @set foobar=%a` on command prompt.    use `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do @set foobar=%%a` in script files

Comment: A lightweight alternative is Gnu On Windows (https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki).  Simply open a command prompt and run `bash`.  Then you can write bash commands.  You can also execute bash scripts.

Comment: Note that if your command includes a pipe then you need to escape it with a caret, for example: for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo foobar^|sed -e s/foo/fu/') do @set foobar=%%a

Answer (score 38):

One needs to be somewhat careful, since the Windows batch command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('command') do @set theValue=%%a
```

does not have the same semantics as the Unix shell statement:

```
theValue=`command`
```

Consider the case where the command fails, causing an error.

In the Unix shell version, the assignment to "theValue" still occurs, any previous value being replaced with an empty value.

In the Windows batch version, it's the "for" command which handles the error, and the "do" clause is never reached -- so any previous value of "theValue" will be retained.

To get more Unix-like semantics in Windows batch script, you must ensure that assignment takes place:

```
set theValue=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('command') do @set theValue=%%a
```

Failing to clear the variable's value when converting a Unix script to Windows batch can be a cause of subtle errors.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the subtle difference between Windows and *nix.

Comment: Also remember to escape any special characters in `command`; e.g.: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('command1 ^| command2') do set VAR=%%a`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart you just saved my day, for a moment I thought it was much harder to assign the output of piped commands to a variable

Answer (score 23):

Here's how I do it when I need a database query's results in my batch file:

```
sqlplus -S schema/schema@db @query.sql> __query.tmp
set /p result=<__query.tmp
del __query.tmp
```

The key is in line 2: "set /p" sets the value of "result" to the value of the first line (only) in "__query.tmp" via the "<" redirection operator.

Answer (score 16):

The only way I've seen it done is if you do this:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('ver') do @set foobar=%a
```

`ver` is the version command for Windows and on my system it produces:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6001]
```

[Source](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/230090-45-windows-batch-file-output-program-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches:

```
@echo off

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
;;set "[[=>"#" 2>&1&set/p "&set "]]==<# & del /q # >nul 2>&1" &::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: --examples

::assigning chcp command output to %code-page% variable
chcp %[[%code-page%]]%
echo 1: %code-page%

::assigning whoami command output to %its-me% variable
whoami %[[%its-me%]]%
echo 2: %its-me%


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
;;set "{{=for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('" &::
;;set "--=') do @set ""                        &::
;;set "}}==%%#""                               &::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: --examples

::assigning ver output to %win-ver% variable
%{{% ver %--%win-ver%}}%
echo 3: %win-ver%


::assigning hostname output to %my-host% variable
%{{% hostname %--%my-host%}}%
echo 4: %my-host%
```

the output of the script:

```
1: Active code page: 65001
2: mypc\user
3: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]
4: mypc
```

Explanation:

**1]** the parts ending with `&::` are end-of-line comment and can be ignored. I've put them only for macro enclosing

**2]** `;;` at the start of the line will be ignored as `;` is a standard delimiter for batch script. It is put there as it reminds a comment and  to further enhance where the macro definitions are assigned.

**3]** the technique used is called 'macro' it assigns command to a variable and when the variable is invoked the command is executed.

**4]** the first macro defined contains two parts:

```
set "[[=>"#" 2>&1&set/p "
```

and

```
set "]]==<# & del /q # >nul 2>&1"
```

separated by `&` which allows me to define them on one line. The first takes the output of a command and redirects it ot a file `#`. And adds `set/p` in order to start the reading the file with `set /p` [technique](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2128) .The second macro finishes the `set /p` reading with `<#` and then deletes the file. The text between two macros is the name of the variable. Something like `set /p myVariable=<#`

**5]** The second macro contains three parts and expanded is just a `for /f` loop. Probably can be done in a more elegant way.

Comment: After reading this many times over, I still am not sure which part is just a decoration, and which part is the actual commands. I trust you this example works, even though I don't understand what it does. How would one approach starting to decipher what's written here? Is there any sort of Windows shell guide anywhere, where one could look up the commands used here?

Comment: @wvxvw - I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set "dateTime="
For /F %%A In ('powershell get-date -format "{yyyyMMdd_HHmm}"') Do Set "dateTime=%%A"
echo %dateTime%
pause
```

[image]
[Official Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) for `for` command