# How to store the hostname in a variable in a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, hostname

I would like to convert this `/bin/sh` syntax into a widely compatible Windows batch script:

```
host=`hostname`
echo ${host}
```

How to do this so that it'll work on any Windows Vista, Windows XP, and Windows 2000 machine?

To clarify: I would then like to go on in the program and use the hostname as stored in the variable `host`.  In other words, the larger goal of the program is not to simply echo the hostname.

Comment: as others have commented - just use pre-existing environment variable `%COMPUTERNAME%` instead

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I usually read command output in to variables using the `FOR` command as it saves having to create temporary files.  For example:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %i IN (`hostname`) DO SET MYVAR=%i
```

Note, the above statement will work on the command line but not in a batch file.  To use it in batch file escape the `%` in the `FOR` statement by putting them twice:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET MYVAR=%%i
ECHO %MYVAR%
```

There's a lot more you can do with `FOR`.  For more details just type `HELP FOR` at command prompt.

Comment: very nice, though that for loop construct is heavily overloaded IMO.  Will switch to use this.  Thanks!

Comment: You're right - FOR is basically the swiss-army knife of batch scripts in that you end up using it to solve most problems.

Comment: If you want to repeat the assignment (For this example it does not make sense, as you would only query the host name once in a run) then don't forget to use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` (see `HELP SETLOCAL`) and use `!MYVAR!` instead of `%MYVAR%`

Comment: The 'hostname' command returns the same thing that is already stored in the %COMPUTERNAME% environment variable.

Comment: The problem with `%COMPUTERNAME%` is that it is in upper case, and `hostname` returns the original case of the host name. If this matters, then the `hostname` approach is needed.

Comment: >echo %hostname%
    %hostname%

    >echo %computername%
    mycomputername

These are Windows 7 command line samples (tried both from restricted account and administrator account). As you can observe, the %computername% env variable is the only one working, the %hostname% must be defined before usage. In Windows the command line env variables are case insensitive, so you can adapt your code as to be suitable for Linux too.

Comment: @DaveWebb, Thanks showing this method. What is the advantage of this method over the `set host=%COMPUTERNAME%` method of setting the computer name to a variable? This seems to be a little more complicated..

Answer (score 68):

hmm - something like this?

```
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
echo %host%
```

**EDIT**: expanding on jitter's answer and using a technique in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command) to set an environment variable with the result of running a command line app:

```
@echo off
hostname.exe > __t.tmp
set /p host=<__t.tmp
del __t.tmp
echo %host%
```

In either case, 'host' is created as an environment variable.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using the environment variable `COMPUTERNAME`:

```
copy "C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\" %SYSTEMROOT%\system32
srvcheck \\%COMPUTERNAME% > c:\shares.txt
echo %COMPUTERNAME%
```

Answer (score 10):

Why not so?:

```
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
echo %host%
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a .bat file with the line

```
hostname
```

in it. That's it. Windows also supports the hostname command.

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear.  wanted to use the value as stored in the variable, not simply echo it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
 echo %host%
```

This one enough. no need of extra loops of big coding.

Comment: could you please explain, how this is better (or at least different) than the identical answers from nine and nine-and-a-half year ago?

Comment: Sorry. didnt check it was answered long ago.just answered so that future user may get some value from it by ensuring.