# how to get the name of the subfolder inside a known folder using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I want to fetch the names of the subfolders inside a folder using windows batch script. Can anyone pls help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the list of directories (folder) within your chosen directory (folder).

```
dir path-to-folder /ad
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How could I store the name of that subfolder for subsequent use? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry, but somebody seems to have [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998366/how-to-store-hostname-in-a-variable-in-a-bat-file) before.