# How can I use an environment variable in a npm script on windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

In my `package.json` file I have a script defined like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js"
}
```

I want to pass it my hostname, which is a Windows environemnt variable called `HOSTNAME`. I have tried the following solutions, but neither one seems to work:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --host HOSTNAME"
```

and

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --host %HOSTNAME%"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The one with `%HOSTNAME%` worked fine for me.

Comment: If i type just HOSTNAME in the cmd it works but not through the script or with the % :(

Comment: I did something wrong when I did the test. I set the hostname variable manually with `set HOSTNAME=asdf`, which overrided the hostname tool. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax on Windows is `%envvariable%`. It doesn't work for you because `hostname` is an application (hostname.exe) that outputs the hostname, not an environmental variable. One solution is to use the variable `COMPUTERNAME` instead.

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --host %COMPUTERNAME%"
```

According to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490919.aspx) the hostname tool

> Displays the host name portion of the full computer name of the computer.

So `COMPUTERNAME` might not display entirely what you want, but I would give it a shot. There is some info regarding `COMPUTERNAME` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998366/how-to-store-the-hostname-in-a-variable-in-a-bat-file).

I tried a few clever tricks, such as storing the output of hostname.exe in a new environment variable:

```
"start": "hostname > host.txt && set /P HOST= < host.txt && webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --host %HOST%"
"start": "for /f %i in ('hostname') do set HOST=%i && webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --host %HOST%"
```

I couldn't get it to work.