# Can I store the output of a command in a variable in batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file

I want to dir a folder and get in a variable all the names of the *.csv files.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch files: How to set a variable with the result of a command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Bash you can try:

```
dirlist=`ls -1 *.csv`
echo "$dirlist"
```

Under windows you can read the following Q and A:

[Windows batch files: How to set a variable with the result of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command)

Something like:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir') do @set foobar=%%a
```

Change 'dir' to what you want. I have no windows machine close by, so cannot test.

Comment: Why answer a duplicate question?

Comment: And because it makes it easy for us Googlers to find the answer even when Google points us to the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for a duplicate response, but StackOverflow has reputation counters that impede me from certain actions.

When executing directly on the command-prompt, use the following form:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('whoami') do @set myaccount=%a
```

The form in previous answer is intended when used in a .bat or .cmd file.