# Windows Batch: How to set the output of one command as a variable and use it in another command?

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I'm trying to parse a variable. Say NAMELIST = "AAA BBB CCC" and store each one as a variable. Then, these new variables must be used in another command. Eg:

```
perl.exe C:\action.pl <VAR1>
perl.exe C:\action.pl <VAR2>
perl.exe C:\action.pl <VAR3>
```

I'm new to Windows Batch so any help would be appreciated.

I am aware of this thread but don't fully understand the solution

[Windows batch files: How to set a variable with the result of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer to "store each one in a variable", the involved concept here is *array*. You may split the words of NAMELIST variable into 3 array elements this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%a in (%namelist%) do (
   set /A i=i+1
   set VAR!i!=%%a
)
```

This way, you may use each array element directly:

```
perl.exe C:\action.pl %VAR1%
perl.exe C:\action.pl %VAR2%
perl.exe C:\action.pl %VAR3%
```

Or, in a simpler way using a loop:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do perl.exe C:\action.pl !VAR%%i!
```

**EDIT**: You may use this method with an unlimited number of values in the NAMELIST variable, just use the previous value of %i% instead the 3 (better yet, change it by "n"). I also suggest you to use the standard array notation this way: `VAR[%%i]`:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set namelist=AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF
set n=0
for %%a in (%namelist%) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set VAR[!n!]=%%a
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do perl.exe C:\action.pl !VAR[%%i]!
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Is there a way to eliminate specifying 3 in the call loop 
   
   "for /L %%i in (1,1,3)"

Answer (score 0):

Variables in batch can be set by using for loop. I'll try to explain the example given in the link.

> for /f "delims=" %%a in (`command`) do @set theValue=%%a

Here For /F is used to break up the output into tokens. "delims=" means no explicit separator is given so "space" is assumed. %%a is like index variable of loop however instead of traditional index variable in programming languages where index variable has a numeric value index variables in batch can store the tokens i.e. output of command. set command then sets the variable "theValue" to %%a which holds the output/token of the command. 
Thus if the statement is:

```
 for /f "delims=" %%a in (`echo Hi everyone!`) do @set theValue=%%a

theValue will then hold "Hi" as it is the first token seprated by space.
```

You can specify your own separator as per your requirement. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank Gaurav. But how do I use a variable say NAMELIST instead of "echo Hi everyone". I tried to replace it with a variable but it isn't working for me.

Comment: for /f "delims=" %%a in (`echo %NAMELIST%`) do @set theValue=%%a 
You tried this?

Comment: Yes. nevermind, it was a fault with our environment. I rebooted and tried and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Aacini's solution seems better though :P Sorry. But I can't upvote anyway. Just joined SO and need rep before I can upvote