# Windows Batch - Check if one command variable appears in another command variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I am struggling to get the output required.

I am using a 2 commands to get 2 variables on a device, across multiple devices. I am unsure how to cross reference these to get the output I would like. I am trying to see if any of the contents of **DEVPACKAGE** appears in the contents of **packages**, if they don't appear in **packages** return an error. I assume it is something similar to [[Windows Batch: How to set the output of one command as a variable and use it in another command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961978/windows-batch-how-to-set-the-output-of-one-command-as-a-variable-and-use-it-in][1]) but I cannot see how to apply it to my current variables.

I understand that some of my methods may be crude. I have only been seriously looking into batch file construction for a week.

`DEVPACKAGE`, `Package` and attempted output are as below:

```
::Global
@echo off

set AAPT=tools\aapt.exe
set GREP=tools\grep.exe
set CUT=tools\cut.exe

:: Check Gold Build applications
cls
@echo.
@echo ------------------------ CHECK APPLICATIONS INSTALLED --------------------------

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
::EXTRACT PACKAGENAME FROM APK
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%N IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%O
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%N
        for /f "delims=" %%P in ('dir /b ^"APKs\*.apk^"') do (
            SET APK=%%P
            for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%Q in ('%AAPT% d badging APKs\!APK! ^| !GREP! "package: name=" ^| !CUT! -d' -f2') do (
                set package=%%Q
                if "!package!" == "" set package=Unknown (
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
::EXTRACT INSTALLED PACKAGENAME
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%R IN ('adb devices') DO (
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%U IN ('adb shell "pm list packages" ^| !CUT! -f 2 -d ":"^') DO (
        SET DEVPACKAGE=%%U
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
::CHECK IF INSTALLED APPEARS IN PACKAGENAME FROM APK FOLDER
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%V IN ('adb devices') DO (
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        for /f "delims=" %%W in ('dir /b ^"APKs\*.apk^"') do (
            IF !DEVPACKAGE! NEQ !package! (
                echo Device !SERIAL! does not have !package! installed
                ) else (
                echo Device !SERIAL! has all APKs installed correctly
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
@pause
```

I would a variable output similar to:

```
------------------------ CHECK APPLICATIONS INSTALLED --------------------------

Device <SERIAL1> does not have <APK2> installed
Device <SERIAL3> does not have <APK1> installed
Device <SERIAL22> does not have <APK7> installed

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no VAR1 and VAR2 in your code....

Comment: I suppose you want to check if `DEVPACKAGE` contains `package` ? Or the other way?

Comment: thats correct I want to check if `DEVPACKAGE` appears in `package`

Comment: and in the message i would like to have the package name to correspond  to the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "DEVPACKAGE_=!DEVPACKAGE:"=""!"
echo !package!|find "!DEVPACKAGE_!" >nul 2>nul && (
   echo it is contained
)||(
   echo it is NOT contained
)
```

The temporary variable `DEVPACKAGE_` is needed to double the `"` so if the string contains it will be processed correctly by the `FIND` command.

You can do it with cmd internals commands only too:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpasion
if "%package%" equ "!package:%DEVPACKAGE%=!" (
  echo it is NOT contained
) else (
  echo it is contained
)
```

In theory the second approach should be faster but there more characters that could break it.

Comment: I have added this to the end and it is just bringing through `it is NOT contained`. Have i done something wrong here as there is not accosiated `!package!` name? Sorry if its a silly question

Comment: @beecho01 - you need to use [variable replacement](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) but not directly to compare the devpackage and package. If all occurrences  of `devpackage` are replaced in `package` and the strings are equal then it is not contained. At the moment you are just checking if `devpackage` is equal to `package` - try with the whole condition copied.