# How to assign the value of batch operation to a variable?

Tags: batch-file

What is the Windows/batch version of this Bash script below:

```
MY_VAR=`date`
echo $MY_VAR
```

affecting the value of an operation back into a var?

In windows I been trying:

```
set MY_VAR=%date /T%
set MY_VAR=!date /T!
...
echo %MY_VAR%
```

I have been looking at: 
[Windows batch files: How to set a variable with the result of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command)
without any success...

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('date /T') do set MY_VAR=%i
```

If you're using a batch file, then you'd need to escape the `%` by using a double percent sign `%%`.

Comment: Thanks I just tried it and it works! But is there a more succint way of doing the same operation?

Comment: +1 Using a for /f is the usual method to capture text to a variable.  `find` and `findstr` are often also used to filter certain lines from the output or text file.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the default `date` variable:

```
set var=%date%
Echo %var%
```

Or directly:

```
Echo %date%
```

That will do exactly the same thing with half the effort.

Mona.