# How can I read db field with batch script?

Tags: oracle, batch-file

I want to use batch script to read a field from oracle Db table. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you have in mind?

Comment: sorry, batch file means, you want to automate select query and download into a file, is it unix?

Comment: I firstly add some data to DB and then I take count of rows which already inserted to DB. I want to take this number with batch script and assign to a variable in batch script side.

Comment: No, not unix. System is windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it in a decent fashion. But can be done by redirectingt he query output to a file, and then read from it. Please see below.

```
sqlplus -S schema/schema@db @query.sql> __query.tmp
set /p result=<__query.tmp
del __query.tmp
```

The key is in line 2: "`set /p`" sets the value of "result" to the value of the first line (only) in "__query.tmp" via the "<" redirection operator.

**Courtesy of this thread :** [Windows batch files: How to set a variable with the result of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command)

***EDIT:***
inside your query file, please add the below lines. And then your query!

```
set pages 0;
set heading off; 
set feedback off;
```

Comment: result comes as                                                   COUNT(*)
----------
      2015
I want to take just 2015 number not with field name.

Comment: inside your query file, please add the below lines. Abd then your query!
`set pages 0; 
set heading off; 
set feedback off;`

Comment: Most welcome, good day!