# How can i set exe file output to variable in batch file?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, assign

I have execution file **(print.exe)** which will print some numbers.I want to use those numbers. For that I wrote a batch file.

build.bat

**set a=print.exe**

**FOR %I IN a DO prompt.exe %I%**

I used the above 2 lines. But its not working. If, it is kernel command, the first line is working. For exe, it didn't work. How can i store the print.exe file output to variable.?

Comment: Why are you using prompt.exe ?  prompt is an internal command.  Please explain the task a little more.

Comment: by using prompt.exe and output of print, i am doing some other calculation. Okay i will rename it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch files: How to set a variable with the result of a command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command)

Comment: No. result of kernel command is working fine. Result of exe file is not working. Thats why i raised this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Batch file below execute **print.exe** and get its output in `numbers` variable:

```
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('print.exe') do set numbers=%%a

echo Output of print.exe is: %numbers%
```