# How to insert a variable inside the sentence

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am trying to automate multiple switch backups from the windows host, for this i have made below script

```
plink.exe admin@xxxx -pw *** configupload -p ftp \xxx,eccadmin,config.txt,xxx
```

The above script is taking backup successfully, but I want to insert date and time stamp into the config file name, say `2015-01-01-config.txt`.

I have tried this:

```
set arg1= date/T
plink.exe admin@xxxx -pw *** configupload -p ftp \xxx,eccadmin,%arg1%config.txt,xxx
```

but it doesn't work. If you have a better idea, please answer.

Comment: `plink.exe admin@xxxx -pw *** configupload -p ftp \xxx,eccadmin,%date:/=-%-config.txt,xxx`

Answer (score 0):

You should write a bit more than just "assign a string to a variable". First, you really need current date in some format, this is done as displayed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command), just replace the command `ver` for `date /t`. I have found that I need to use `"delims= "` with a space in the filter string to get the correct value in a variable. Then you do the command as normal, and then you rename `config.txt` to a new name.

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('date /t') do @set arg1=%%a
plink.exe admin@xxxx -pw *** configupload -p ftp \xxx,eccadmin,config.txt,xxx
ren config.txt %arg1%.config.txt
```

Should do.

Comment: if you check my script it is login to remote host by ftp. So i can't rename a config file because it is uploaded to that host. i have to rename some how before upload.

Comment: So it's *upload*, not *download*? And you need to rename the config at remote side, right?`