# Can not use commands after set var= command

Tags: batch-file, set, var

I am writing a file to silently install and application then move it to the correct directory and then install an update for the application. The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to use the move copy or del commands in the same line as the var.

```
    set var="c:\program file (x86)\program\program.exe" /qn
    set var1= move "c:\program file (x86)\program\program.exe" "c:\"
```

Any assistance will be very much appreciated!

Comment: The `set` command does not run anything. It just sets a variable to a string. Your string is "move blah blah".

Comment: I thing this is what you want -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command

Comment: @RaymondChen - are you the `real` Raymond Chen?

Comment: @npocmaka I see where you are going and I think that is what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
set v
```

to see it working. What do you expect to happen?