# is this possible? "ECHO. The time is: %time /T%"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a stats.bat program that will refresh in order to show me the most up to date data that I can have.

I have tried just about ever thing to my knowledge.

In the script I have I want it to show time but I want it to something like this.

```
ECHO The Time Is: %time /T%
```

Where the "%time /T%" will show the time on the same line as the ECHO line.

I have tried researching on it but I just cant find anything on the subject.

Comment: Do you know that format of time output by `time /T` as well as when using `echo %TIME%` depends on Windows region and language settings specified for the current user account. If your batch file should output the time always in same format, you need the command `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS get localdatetime` and extra code to output the time in the format you want independent on region and language settings.

Comment: i just did this: for /f "delims=" %%a in ('time /T') do @set foobar=%%a
echo The Time Is: = %foobar%

Answer (score 2):

Just a neat little trick using SET /P with nul redirection.

```
 @echo off
 set /p ".=The time is = "<nul &TIME /T
 pause
```

Comment: you even don't need the `.`: `set /p "=The time is = "<nul &TIME /T`

Comment: @Stephan just my coding style in that instance.

Comment: @sqashman: wasn't a critique, just a note. (I also mostly use `.`)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('time /T') do @set foobar=%%a
echo The Time Is: = %foobar%
```

For further discussion, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command).

Answer (score 0):

I got it too work guys if you want to see what i was doing dm me. also this was the code i used thanks to "i_am_jorf"

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('time /T') do @set foobar=%%a
echo The Time Is: = %foobar%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ECHO The time is %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
```

will give you:

```
The time is 14:59:02
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using this cmd

for /F "tokens=1" %%i in ('time /t') do set mytime=%%i

echo "time is = " %mytime:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6%

the result is:  time is = 094752.78

instead, echo %time%

9:47:52.78