# How to save cmd output as file name

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm running a command line script on multiple PC's and i'm trying to save username as a file name so i can see who's information i'm viewing later on.

In the command line script i run Whoami and i'd like to save it as "user"."file type". I'm trying to do this in a command line script because I always do it manually in command line and am trying to automate this process so I can do it faster.

If you know how to do it in a better way do share.

Comment: Perhaps these threads are interesting for you: [Assign Command output to Variable in Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16203629), [Set the value of a variable with the result of a command in a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/889518), [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820).

Comment: ty, now i have username in a variable, how do i put it as a file name?

Comment: like `%variable%.txt`. There is also the system variable `%username%`, which may do for you.

Comment: `DIR >"%USERNAME%.txt"` or `ECHO>"%USERNAME%.txt" this information` There are many options with redirection of the output. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: >%USERNAME%.txt worked in the end. Ty

Answer (score 0):

whoami > test.txt

> tells it to go to a file and "test.txt" will be generated wherever your CMD CurDir is.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Windows Environment variables `%USERNAME%` and possibly `%USERDOMAIN%` if the domain is needed.

`%USERNAME%` does not return the domain by itself.

Full list of standard environment variables: [How-to: Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

Use these in the command as needed. For example:

```
dir > %USERNAME%.txt
```

If you need the domain in there:

```
dir > %USERDOMAIN%_%USERNAME%.txt
```

(using `_` to separate domain and username instead of `\` since filename cannot contain `\`)

Remember to use  `>>` instead of `>` if you don't want the file to be overwritten each time the command is run.

You may want to direct errors and standard output as needed: [Redirecting error messages from Command Prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/redirecting-error-command-prompt)